# Unity , dll is not allowed to be included or does not exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

I'm Trying to build my project to standalone however I'm getthing this error that is not allowing me to build. It's an error related to the TweetInvi Lib.

This is the Error `ArgumentException: The Assembly System.Threading.Tasks is referenced by Tweetinvi ('Assets/Plugins/Tweetinvi.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.`

I'm Using Unity 2017.2 and my Player Settigns are > .NET 4.6
The TweetInvi.dll Is Inside my Plugins Folder

Anyone has any soulution?

Comment: I know you probably want an answer quickly but I wanted to say that I created a work item for me to ensure that Unity is supported.

You can find the work item here : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/630

Comment: Can you try using an older version of TweetInvi?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

- Add System.Configuration.dll your Plugins folder.
- In Build Settings > Player Settings > API Compatibility Level, change the .NET 
  setting.

Then try to build again

Comment: change options in Unity, player setting, oter settings: Api compatibility level: .Net 4.6